# MVC HTTPS redirection when behind a load balancer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, elastic-load-balancer

I'm using MVC5 in some IIS servers on Amazon EC2, behind a Amazon Elastic Load Balancer. IIS servers runs only HTTP protocol, and ELB converts to HTTPS.

IIS server doesn't know if user is accessing thru HTTPS, so I have a rewrite rule checking "X-Forwarded-Proto" header to redirect user to HTTPS.

Unfortunately, when a login is required, MVC/IIS redirects user to a **logon page in HTTP**.

If I check my website in a tool like http://www.redirect-checker.org/ I get these type of results:

> http://example.com/
>
> 301 Moved Permanently (my URL rewrite rule)
>
> https://example.com/
>
> 302 Found (Login-required redirect -> why to HTTP?)
>
> http://example.com/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2F
>
> 301 Moved Permanently (again my URL rewrite rule)
>
> https://example.com/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2F
>
> 200 OK

Am I missing something?

Can I configure login-redirect to keep protocol, eliminating one of these redirects?

Better yet, can I somehow precede login-redirect rule and make it force HTTPS, in order to have only one redirect?

Thanks a lot!

**Appendix:**
I checked that commands like "RedirectToAction" send address like "/Index2", not the whole "http://example.com/Index2". This is fine, so it keeps the user protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using ASP.NET forms authentication, have a look in your `web.config` for your `Authentication` configuration and add `requireSsl="true"` to the `<forms>` element, as below:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Actually I'm using AspNet.Identity v2.2.1. This seems to be the way, but I couldn't find a requireSSL equivalent.

Comment: It might be worth having a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615017/asp-net-identity-login-redirect-enforce-protocol-https